# Change icon src upon menu item active - Ionic 5

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native, ionic5

I have an Ionic + Electron desktop application and upon current item selection from the menu I wish to change the icon src of the selected item. Currently I am able to change the color of the item text alone using the 'routerLinkActive' attribute. How can I also change the src of the ion-icon upon link active?

```
   <ion-item lines="none" routerLinkActive="activeHighlight" routerLink="/dashboard" mode="md" class="menuItems">
      <ion-icon src="assets/icon/Dashboard.svg" slot="start"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Dashboard</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
```

This is how I am changing the styling of ion-label when link is active, I also wish to change the icon to the same color. For that I am trying to add another svg of the same icon to the src only when that link is active.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, I understood your question right.
If you want to make your icon src dynamic you can just use a variable instead of hard coding it.
Example:

```
<ion-img class="headerLogo" [src]="imageSource"></ion-img>
```

Ts file:

```
imageSource = "assets/icon/Dashboard.svg"
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the suggestion. But I am actually looking for some way to identify which page is currently active from the app.ts file so that I can dynamically change the imageSrc.

Comment: @MJ2410 you can create a service which detects the route changes and return the current url. From there you could change the src url.